# Display an image from a buffer

Tags: opencv, camera, mat

I have a buffer returned by a Mono8 (grayscale) camera. I want to save each returned frame.
I am doing like this using opencv:

```
Mat Image;
//Save the current Frame.
 Image=Mat(mFrame->Height,mFrame->Width,CV_8UC1);
 memcpy(Image.data,mFrame->ImageBuffer,mFrame->ImageBufferSize);
 imwrite("Frame numero"+ mConvertInttoString(nbFrame)+".jpg",Image);
```

The result is a black images. What is wrong?

Comment: This code is correct. In fact, my errror is about the buffer acquired by camera

Comment: Is mFrame->ImageBuffer defined as "unsigned char*" ? Has  mFrame->ImageBufferSize the correct value (Height*Width*sizeof(unsigned char)) ?